# Rally Rest API: Java code to fetch userStory /TestCases/Defect Count for a given project

Tags: java, api, rest, rally

Team,

I am looking for java program to fetch count of user stories, test cases, and defect total for a given project.

i tried to dump all the hierarchical data - and do data mining on that - to build the data metrics - but its taking too much time - i have enormous data (2000 projects, each proejct has 3/4 thousand user stories)

is there any query - where i can get required data for one project in one stretch ?

Pls help.

Thanks
VG

Answer (score 3):

For each project, for each type simply do a query with a page size of one and inspect the TotalResultCount property.  That will give you the total number of matching records without actually retrieving all the data.

The following example shows how to do this with the [Rally REST Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava):

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "user@company.com", "password");

//retrieve only 1   
QueryRequest defectCount = new QueryRequest("defect");
defects.setPageSize(1);
defects.setLimit(1);

//for a specific project
defectCount.setProject("/project/12345");
defectCount.setScopedUp(false);
defectCount.setScopedDown(false);

QueryResponse defectCountResponse = restApi.query(defectCount);
int total = defectCountResponse.getTotalResultCount();
```